# Could we do backward elimination with mixed model using lmer

Tags: r

I used the following syntax for the mixed model and then step but it did not work.

Does it normally work like this or I actually can not use backward elimination with lmer? Thanks!

```
fullmodel<-lmer(Eeff~NDF+ADF+CP+NEL+DMI+FCM + (1|Study),data=na.omit(phuong))
step(fullmodel, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it, just not with the step function.  Since your model is just additive it shouldn't take that long to do by hand.

Comment: and `drop1` does work, I believe.  Also (as commented elsewhere) try Googling "Harrell stepwise" for some of the more trenchant criticisms of stepwise approaches ...

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with [`lmerTest`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/index.html) package:

```
library(lmerTest)
step(fullmodel)
```

After testing this function with my rather complex data, it does seem to produce feasible model alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

The function you want is `stepAIC` from the `MASS` package.

`stepAIC` (and `step`) use AIC by default, which is asymptotically equivalent to leave-one-out cross validation.

As for the trenchant criticisms, expert knowledge is a great starting point for model selection, but I too often see this used as an excuse to pass the responsibility for making complex statistical decisions off to an applied researcher who doesn't understand statistics.

Edit: sorry, my bad, misread your question, I thought you said 'lme' instead of 'lmer'. I have no idea whether stepAIC supports lmer.

Comment: As I said in the comments above, I'm pretty sure that `stepAIC` does *not* work with `lmer`.  However, `drop1` works fine with the development version. I certainly don't want to pass anything off, but I also don't feel a responsibility to spend a lot of effort making `stepAIC` work ...